# udev rule for detecting keyboard not working

Tags: udev

Here is my rules file:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input",\
SUBSYSTEMS="usb",\
ACTION=="add",\
ATTRS{idVendor}=="2a7a",\
RUN+="/usr/bin/xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'"
```

And here is the output of `udevadm test (device path)`

```
Invalid inotify descriptor.
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:2A7A:8A47.0020/input/input64/event5
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event5
MAJOR=13
MINOR=69
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=input
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
ID_VENDOR=2a7a
ID_VENDOR_ENC=2a7a
ID_VENDOR_ID=2a7a
ID_MODEL=CASUE_USB_KB
ID_MODEL_ENC=CASUE\x20USB\x20KB
ID_MODEL_ID=8a47
ID_REVISION=0001
ID_SERIAL=2a7a_CASUE_USB_KB
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_BUS=usb
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030000:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
.INPUT_CLASS=kbd
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-2a7a_CASUE_USB_KB-event-kbd /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-event-kbd
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2_1_0
XKBMODEL=pc105
XKBLAYOUT=tr
XKBVARIANT=
XKBOPTIONS=
BACKSPACE=guess
TAGS=:power-switch:
LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=3/2a7a/8a47:usb-0000:00:14.0-2
USEC_INITIALIZED=16964855649
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

I have noticed that it outputted `Invalid inotify descriptor.`. I searched it and found nothing.

I tried `udevadm trigger` and replugging my keyboard. None worked.

I tried adding `export DISPLAY=:0`, removing `SUBSYTEMS` and `ATTR{idVendor}` as well. Still didn't work.

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `SUBSYTEMS=="usb"`? And `ATTRS{idVendor}`?

Comment: @meuh Yes, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: @AliFurkan Did you ever figure out how to fix the `Invalid inotify descriptor`? It seems to stop the `udevadm test` command from giving detailed output about what udev rules are triggered in response to a USB key being inserted for instance.

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy I got a new keyboard few days ago